# How can i compare the current time to my TimePickerDialog time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

*Alarmclock*

```
public class Wecker extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView Alarm1
        int A1Stunde,A1Minute
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_wecker);
  //current Time
        

Date currentTime = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

   //ring-tone
       



final Uri alert  = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            final  Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),  alert);
         ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                
    
 //for layout      
       



Alarm1 = findViewById(R.id.Alarm1);
            
 //OnClickListener for TimePicker
        

Alarm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           

             @Override
//timePicker for hours and minutes (hours = Stunde)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                                    Wecker.this,
                                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                        @Override
                                

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int Stunde, int Minute) {
                                    A1Stunde = Stunde;
                                    A1Minute = Minute;

                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar.set(0,0,0,A1Stunde,A1Minute);

                                Alarm1.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa",calendar));

                            } 
                        },24,0,true

                );

 //this part is to update the timepicker

timePickerDialog.updateTime(A1Stunde,A1Minute);
                timePickerDialog.show();
```

//comparison between currentTime and TimePickerDialog

```
Timer t = new Timer();
                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (currentTime.equals(TimePickerDialog))
    
                            ringtone.play();
    
                        else
                            ringtone.stop();
    
                    }
                },0,1000);
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    }
```

*If you need more Info please let me know, its my first android Studio Project for my school and im pretty lost. Im Trying to make an AlarmClock which is active while currentTime = TimePickerDialog, the format between currentTime and TimePickerDialog is wrong *

Comment: The `Date` class was long ago supplanted by `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: and how do i use it?

Comment: The `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes were supplanted years ago by the executor service framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the current time and your TimePickerDialog into UNIX timestamp first and then compare them.